# Creating nested xml in groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

I have an issue where I'm trying to dynamically create nested xml nodes in groovy. When I say dynamic, I mean using a StringTokenizer, so passing in a string "a.b", would give be a node like this:

```
<a>
  <b></b>
</a>
```

I already have the following code that can create a node with values and attributes (using a MarkupBuilder and StringWriter)

```
"${node.node_name}"(node.attributes, node.value);
```

If I were to replace this with

```
a{b()}
```

That would give be a nested node, but I need to create the node dynamically. I'm guessing that I'd use a StringTokenizer and do something like this

```
while(tokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
    final String nodeName = tokenizer.nextToken();
     if(tokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
         // create child node
     } else {
         // add value and attribute to final nested node
         "${nodeName}"(node.attributes, node.value);
     }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with `inject` to build up a chain of Closures which when run generates the xml:

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

def property = 'a.b.c.d.e.f'
def leafProperties = [id:10, something:'else']

def writer = new StringWriter()
new MarkupBuilder(writer).with { xml ->
    property.split(/\./).reverse().inject(null) { c, p ->
        c ? { x -> xml."$p"(c) } : { x -> xml."$p"(leafProperties) }
    }()
}

println writer.toString()
```

Comment: Thanks, that does successfully create a nested node. How would I go about adding attributes/values to the final node (most nested)? I tried adding them to a few places but kept getting errors.

Comment: Updated answer...is that what you mean?

Comment: I tried that and I got a MissingMethodException:No signature of method: java.lang.String.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap, java.lang.String) values: [[:], 012] .

Here I've passed in an empty map for the attributes, and a string for the value.

Comment: Apoligies, I misread the update. That's all working now, thank you very much.

Comment: No worries! Have fun!